# Can't run program because it asks me to attach on process

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm new to C# Programming, and instead of just letting me run the code by pressing F5, "Attach..." appears where the Run button should be and it won't let me run the code.
This has happened me twice by now and I don't know how to make the "Run" button appear again, because I can't test any program I write.

Comment: Are you developing a console program ? If it is a library, you have to attach the process using your library.

Comment: Yes I am developing a console program.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make sure you have your solution opened, then right click on your project > Set as Start Up Project

Comment: Why isn't my project showing up in the solution explorer?
Any other way that I can archieve that?
[link](http://postimg.org/image/iy441fphn/fa172fc5/)

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like you do not have a solution open. You only have a standalone C# file open. Make sure you are opening the `.sln` file to open your project.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved it!
But is it a bug of the program? Because I usually open the project from the "Recent projects" section, should I open it from the Open project..?
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I have x64 on my mashine and after installing Visual Studio I couldn't run the code same as you. I solved the issue by deleting this Path system's variable which is in **System Properties** > **Advanced** then **Environment Variables** at the bottom. Go to the **System Variables**, select **Path** and **Edit**. Then delete: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet"**. The problem was that this path was used for reading dotnet folder instead of "C:\Program Files\dotnet".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably used option recent files which is next to recent projects and solutions option. You still can use recent projects and solutions menu item. There is no bug here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening because I opened a blank project, when I switched to a `Console App Template` I could see the run Icon.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall .NET Framework: Go to "Control Panel" and navigate to "Programs" or "Programs and Features". Look for any entries related to .NET Framework or dotnet, and uninstall them. Make sure to uninstall all versions that are currently installed on your system.

Download the latest .NET Framework: Visit the official Microsoft website (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and download the latest version of the .NET Framework that is compatible with your operating system.

Install the .NET Framework: Once the download is complete, run the installer and follow the on-screen instructions to install the .NET Framework on your system. Make sure to choose the appropriate options and configurations based on your requirements.

Restart your computer: After the installation is complete, restart your computer to ensure the changes take effect.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `File` > `Add` > `Existing Project` and select the one you want to execute.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Go to `%appdata%` and delete the Visual Studio folder, this will reset Visual Studio and fix this error.

Comment: Not sure how is this related to the problem/solution. Do you have a reference?